# Problem with App Module adding Facebook provider

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, module

I am making an app and using Angular/ionic and I am trying to place the Facebook provider, but I am getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ..., ?[object Object]?
```

My app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageModule} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import {LoginPageModule} from './pages/login/login.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,



  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
   Facebook <------------------------- ERROR
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone help me?

Is the Facebook provider outdated? I am following a toturial and doing all steps right, but after I place the provider I get this error

Answer (score 0):

For angular 2+ you should use:

`@ionic-native/facebook/ngx` (notice `ngx`)

`ngx` means a`ng`ular ne`x`t gen (angular 2+)

[Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook)

Edit: looking into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874636/angular-2-error-invalid-provider-only-instances-of-provider-and-type-are-allo), the error you're getting is probably because of router ( `{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },` ) , not facebook provider.

Comment: iplaced that and it doesnt fix :c

Comment: @Drprince100100 i checked it and it worked forr me. what's your new error?

Comment: @Drprince100100 1. check if `@ionic-native/core` is installed as well. 2. check your import statement is like : `import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';` 3. you can see in here it's working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hyhrru?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts how you're sure this error is comming from facebook mport?

Comment: @Drprince100100 updated the answer. probably the error is from router provider : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874636/angular-2-error-invalid-provider-only-instances-of-provider-and-type-are-allo